# DropDown menu on SideNav | Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng

I need this. http://prntscr.com/pckz8t . How I can implement such dropdown function  with angular component. I dont want to write a lot of nativ code. Maybe there is some solution with Angular Material or PrimeNg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called Accordion. Many UI framework have their implementation of this:

- [Ng-Bootrap Accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples)
- [PrimeNg Accordion](http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion)
- [Angular Material Expansion panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)